# sqlsrv_fetch_array function in PHP does not work

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I'm using the function `sqlsrv_fetch_array` in a lot of pages in my website,
but for some reason, in a specific case it doesn't work.

I sent the query manually, in the SQL and it works fine.
Here is the result of the query I've sent:

```
4721    fino    fino@gmail.com  Apr 28 2016  7:27PM 127.0.0.1   3   3   Fino Nab    MA  educ    1   1   60  NULL    Danda
```

The name of the variable that handles the result is `$infoQuery`.

When I print `sqlsrv_num_rows($infoQuery)`, the result is 1 ( correct result ).

```
echo sqlsrv_num_rows( $infoQuery ); // result is 1 ( correct result )
```

But when I try to do that:

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $infoQuery ) ) {
    echo "Just printing..";
}
```

It prints nothing, which means, it doesn't work.
I'm using PHP 7, with SQL SERVER 2012, windows 7.
Does anyone has an idea for why it happens?

Comment: I don't see a way to figure out what's going wrong with the information you've provided here. You say you use `sqlsrv_fetch_array` successfully in other pages on your site, so there must be something wrong with the way this specific query is being executed. Try to create an **[mcve]** and **[edit]** your question to include it.

Comment: The problem isn't with the query, it runs perfectly when I send it directly to SQL.

Comment: I understand that. I meant that something must be wrong with the way it's being executed in PHP.

Comment: Have you used `sqlsrv_fetch_array($infoQuery)` at all before that loop, for example in a `var_dump()`? If so, you have already "read" the first, and in this case only, row returned by the query and therefore, by the time of the loop, there are no more rows to read, and your `while` loop will return `false` and not run.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you load BOTH dll's listed in the README:
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll

Comment: Is it necessary? I've used sqlsrv functions ( includes sqlsrv_fetch_array ) a lot of times, it's the first time I have issue with that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I used this, It fixed my problem

$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$serverName;Database=$dbName", "$username", "$password");

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COR.CourseID AS id ");

$stmt->execute();

$ind = 0;

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

```
  print_r($row);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

May be the query answare have 2 result you must use sqlsrv_next_result() because the rows afected some times apaears like numer one in the list recordsets

Try this, only if you are sure the response have fields :

```
enter code here

 if ( sqlsrv_num_fields($qry_actcmd) == 0) )  // to verify if it is a record set
                sqlsrv_next_result($qry_actcmd);  //go to next result recordset.

//Now, Fetch the "real" recordset

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $qry_actcmd, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ) )
{
  //....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $infoQuery, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {
    echo "Just printing..";
}
```

If you will get false you can inspect the error you've got:

```
    foreach( sqlsrv_errors() as $error ) {
        echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."<br />";
        echo "code: ".$error[ 'code']."<br />";
        echo "message: ".$error[ 'message']."<br />";
    }
```

Comment: Did you do `var_dump(sqlsrv_fetch_array( $infoQuery, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ));` ?

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: var_dump(sqlsrv_fetch_array( $infoQuery, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ));
prints "bool(false)".

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php seems something wrong with query then. `Returns an array on success, NULL if there are no more rows to return, and FALSE if an error occurs.`

Comment: so why is the function sql_srv_nunrows returns 1? I printed the query a second before I sent it to sqlsrv_query and I sent it manually, it works fine.

Comment: foreach errors returns: SQLSTATE: IMSSP
code: -28
message: The active result for the query contains no fields.